# Register a New User with the Mobile SDK for Android on AWS Cognito

Tags: android, amazon-cognito

Im trying to develop a sing up for AWS Cognito in Android. I just checked the [official doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-android-sdk.html#using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-android-sdk-register) but in the *Register a New User* section there is only the sample for using `SignUpHandler`.

[image]

Checking other sections, for example [Using the JavaScript SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html#using-amazon-cognito-identity-user-pools-javascript-example-registering-user) there is a clear sample using 
`userPool.signUp('username', 'password', attributeList, null, function(err, result)`

Im trying to implement this aproach transpolating the javascript example. But I was wondering if there is any complete sample of sign up for Android?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The handler you noticed is a parameter for the call to sign up, much like 'function(err, result) in the JS example. Take a look at [this part of the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/tutorial-integrating-user-pools-android.html#tutorial-integrating-user-pools-sign-up-users-android), it shows how to use that handler. From the example you screenshotted, it might look like this:

```
userPool.signUpInBackground(userId, password, userAttributes, null, handler);
```

Comment: Hi Jeff thanks for your answer. The sample was in Step 3: Signing up Users for Your App.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete sample using the [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/tutorial-integrating-user-pools-android.html#tutorial-integrating-user-pools-sign-up-users-android) sugested by Jeff:

```
    CognitoUserAttributes attributes = new CognitoUserAttributes();
    attributes.addAttribute("phone_number","+15555555555");
    attributes.addAttribute("email","email@mydomain.com");

    cognitoUserPool.signUp('username', 'password', attributes, null, new SignUpHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(CognitoUser cognitoUser, boolean b, CognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails cognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails) {
            // If the sign up was successful, "user" is a CognitoUser object of the user who was signed up.
            // "codeDeliveryDetails" will contain details about where the confirmation codes will be delivered.
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception e) {
            // Sign up failed, code check the exception for cause and perform remedial actions.
        }
    });
```

The sections *Examples of Using User Pools with the Mobile SDK for Android* seems to be outdated.

Hope to help somebody else ;)